# Nsis 3.09 open source build using SCONS

Tags: build, nsis, scons

I've downloaded Nsis 3.09 source code and would like to build its binaries. Python,scon,zlib and MSVS are already installed.

https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/AppendixG.html

Those instructions are very old and I'm not sure if it's still valid.

Sconstruct

```
opts.Add(EnumVariable('MSVS_VERSION', 'MS Visual C++ version', os.environ.get('MSVS_VERSION'), allowed_values=('6.0', '7.0', '7.1', '8.0', '8.0Exp', '9.0', '9.0Exp', '10.0', '10.0Exp')))
```

I've visual c++ 2013 installed but when i run scons msvs_Version error is reported. Please see image. Sconsctruct values for msvs_version is as above.

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj89S.png)

Please let me know if you could give my any directions as to how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Surbhi

I tried using msvs_version but didn't help

```
scons SKIPUTILS="NSIS Menu" SKIPPLUGINS=all MSVS_VERSION=10.0
```

Comment: Can you paste the text from your error rather than a screen shot. It's much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to say `Using Microsoft tools configuration (10.0)` and not `Using Microsoft tools configuration (<Default>)` so it is somehow not picking up MSVS_VERSION at all?

I gave up trying to keep up with incompatible changes in Scons long ago and instead I use a backdoor that uses Visual Studio from %path% (you must alter the path to vcvars32.bat so it matches your version):

```
@echo off
setlocal
REM NSIS source is in C:\bld\trunk
cd /D C:\bld\trunk
REM zlib-win32 in C:\bld\dep\zlib-win32
REM Assuming python and scons are installed and in %path%

call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"
set ZLIB_W32=C:\bld\dep\zlib-win32
scons MSTOOLKIT=yes MSVC_USE_SCRIPT=None MSVS_VERSION=10.0 VERSION= SKIPUTILS="NSIS Menu" PREFIX="c:\bld\NSIS" install
```